# Answer a request with 200 or 404 based on the content of `Maybe` using Servant

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm currently trying to implement a simple web server with servant. At the moment, I have a `IO (Maybe String)` that I want to expose via a GET endpoint (this might be a database lookup that may or may not return a result, hence `IO` and `Maybe`). If the `Maybe` contains a value, the response should contain this value with a *200 OK* response status. If the `Maybe` is `Nothing`, a *404 Not Found* should be returned.

So far I was following [the tutorial](https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html#the-handler-monad), which also describes handling errors using `throwError`. However, I haven't managed to get it to compile. What I have is the following code:

```hs
type MaybeAPI = "maybe" :> Get '[ JSON] String

server :: Server MaybeAPI
server = stringHandler

maybeAPI :: Proxy MaybeAPI
maybeAPI = Proxy

app :: Application
app = serve maybeAPI server

stringHandler :: Handler String
stringHandler = liftIO $ fmap (\s -> (fromMaybe (throwError err404) s)) ioMaybeString 

ioMaybeString :: IO (Maybe String)
ioMaybeString = return $ Just "foo"

runServer :: IO ()
runServer = run 8081 app
```

I know this is probably more verbose than it needs to be, but I guess it can be simplified as soon as it is working. The problem is the `stringHandler`, for which the compilation fails with:

> No instance for (MonadError ServerError []) arising from a use of ‘throwError’

So my question is: Is this the way to implement such an endpoint in Servant? If so, how can I fix the implementation? My Haskell knowledge is rather limited and I never used `throwError` before, so it's entirely possible that I'm missing something here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is actually rather more fundamental than anything that's specific to Servant or its error handling. [fromMaybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) has type `a -> Maybe a -> a`, and here your `a` has to be a `String`. This means that `throwError err404`, as the first argument to `fromMaybe`, has to itself be if type `String`, which it clearly isn't .

Comment: @RobinZigmond Is there another way to turn the `Maybe String` into `IO String` extracting the value if it's a `Just` and using `throwError err404` if it's `Nothing`?

Comment: Yes there is, and very simply - I'm just finishing up an answer at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the problem is that in the offending line:

```
stringHandler :: Handler String
stringHandler = liftIO $ fmap (\s -> (fromMaybe (throwError err404) s)) ioMaybeString
```

`s` is a `Maybe String`, so to use it as the second argument to `fromMaybe`, the first argument must be a `String` - and `throwError` is never going to produce a string.

Although you talked about your code perhaps being too verbose and you would look at simplifying it later, I think part of the problem here is that in this particular handler you are trying to be *too* concise. Let's try to write this in a more basic, pseudo-imperative style. Since `Handler` is a monad, we can write this in a `do` block which checks the value of `s` and takes the appropriate action:

```
stringHandler :: Handler String
stringHandler = do
    s <- liftIO ioMaybeString
    case s of
        Just str -> return str
        Nothing -> throwError err404
```

Note that `throwError` can produce a value of type `Handler a` for any type it needs to be, which in this case is `String`. And that we have to use `liftIO` on `ioMaybeString` to lift it into the `Handler` monad, else this won't typecheck.

I can understand why you might have thought `fromMaybe` was a good fit here, but fundamentally it isn't - the reason being that it's a "pure" function, that doesn't involve IO at all, whereas when you're talking about throwing server errors then you are absolutely unavoidably doing IO. These things essentially can't mix within a single function. (Which makes the `fmap` inappropriate too - that can certainly be used to "lift" a pure computation to work on IO actions, but here, as I've said, the computation you needed fundamentally isn't pure.)

And if you want to make the `stringHandler` function above more concise, while I don't think it's really an improvement, you could still use `>>=` explicitly instead of the `do` block, without making the code too unreadable:

```
stringHandler = liftIO ioMaybeString >>= f
    where f (Just str) = return str
          f Nothing = throwError err404
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think I get what you're trying to say with the pure vs impure functions. However, your suggested code for `stringHandler` doesn't compile for me. For the line with `throwError` it says _Couldn't match type ‘GHC.IO.Exception.IOException’ with ‘ServerError’_. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that, give me a little while to see if I can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I also tried your second suggestion with `>>=` instead of the `do` block, which gives me _parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)_. This is even more confusing than the other error message where I can roughly understand the problem

Comment: Oh, for that one I just noticed I have a typo with `==` where there should be an `=`. I'll edit to fix that, I can't see anything else wrong so hopefully it's just that. (Still thinking about the `throwError` one, can't yet see why it's complaining about it :/ )

Comment: Ah yes, without the typo and the `FlexibleContexts` language extension I get the same error message

Comment: ok, I think I've figured it out, apologies for the delay - I think going through the `IO` monad is not needed here and is causing the problem, it should work if we just use the `Handler` monad directly. Just to confirm: does the error message refer to a "functional dependency" somewhere? (It should do if what I'm thinking is correct.)

Comment: Yes: Couldn't match type ‘GHC.IO.Exception.IOException’
                     with ‘ServerError’
        arising from a functional dependency between:
          constraint ‘MonadError ServerError IO’ arising from a use of ‘f’
          instance ‘MonadError GHC.IO.Exception.IOException IO’
            at <no location info>

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I've just rewritten the answer in a way that hopefully should now work. The reason it didn't before was essentially that the `do` block was working in the `IO` monad whereas `throwError` requires the `Handler` monad. So the solution is to not involve `IO` but use `Handler` directly - which in this case has required a slightly awkward use of `liftIO` on `ioMaybeError` in order to be able to use it.